# JPA database columns, list as column

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I'm working on a quiz platform that had multiple choice questions and only accepted one correct answer, but I'm now adapting it to accept more than one. I'm converting in the answers `Option` to `List<Option>`, but I started getting an error because I cant have a List as a Column. How should I fix it?

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Question.QuestionTypes.MULTIPLE_CHOICE_QUESTION)
public class MultipleChoiceAnswer extends AnswerDetails {
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Option.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "option_id")
    private List<Option> option = null;
    /*originally:
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "option_id")
        private Option option;
    */
//...
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Question.QuestionTypes.MULTIPLE_CHOICE_QUESTION)
public class MultipleChoiceAnswerItem extends QuestionAnswerItem {

    //FIXME: ERROR IS HERE:
    private List<Integer> optionId = null;
    //originally: private Integer optionId;

//...
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_answer_items",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "question_answer_items_indx_0", columnList = "quiz_id"),
        })
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "question_answer_type",
        columnDefinition = "varchar(32) not null default 'multiple_choice'",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class QuestionAnswerItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
//...
```

And I started to get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: question_answer_items, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(option_id)]
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: question_answer_items, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(option_id)]
> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: question_answer_items, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(option_id)]

Comment: You cannot store multiple values in one column. So you have to create a separte table

Comment: You have used the wrong mapping. You should use a OneToMany for a List. ManyToOne would be used to map this same relationship to represent that each Option (many) has one MultipleChoiceAnswer associated to it, and requires a foreign key within the Option table. Or you need a separate relational table akin to a ManyToMany mapping.